# Angular material spacing classes like in bootstrap v4

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have been doing searching without any answers to the above problem.

Is there any method we could use classes for spacing like "pt-2" for setting the padding-top property in Angular material?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Angular Material provides that functionality. If you want to apply custom CSS to material components, there are a couple different options. I personally prefer using `::ng-deep`